# jQuery: Update masonry columnwidth on window resize, twice

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to switch between columnwidths using the jQuery masonry plugin, dependant on the browser window size. So if the browser window is less that 1700px you'll switch from 4 columns down to 3, then when the browser window is less than 1200px, you'll switch down from 3 to 2.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#thumb-wrap').masonry({
      itemSelector: '#thumb-container',
      // set columnWidth a fraction of the container width
      columnWidth: function(containerWidth) {
            var num = (containerWidth > 1700) ? 4 : 3;
            var num = (containerWidth > 1200) ? 3 : 2;
            return containerWidth / num;
        }

      });
});
```

But I'm having problems implementing this, I can get one function to work, but to switch the columnwidth twice is proving to be difficult. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be because you're using `var num` twice. Once it's declared, you don't need to declare it again.

```
var num = (containerWidth > 1200) ? 3 : 2;
num = (containerWidth > 1700) ? 4 : num;
```

Comment: this still doesn't work, now it only switches down at 1200 and not implementing the 1700px switch

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You need to reverse it since you're using greater than and the second call will always be true if the size is above 1700. I have edited my answer.